# Making a simple rich text editor with Ruby on Rails, how should I put my text I want to edit in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, iframe, wysiwyg

Following the example here:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand/

I've discovered that I need an iframe for the content that I actually want to edit.

So, here is how I create my "editor":
on my main page:

```
<%= text_area_tag :selected_text, :style => "display: none" %>
<%= text_area_tag :suggested_text, :label=>false, :resizable => false, :style => "display: none"%>
<%= render :partial => "/shared/simple_editor", :locals => {:text_box => "suggested_text", :initial_text => "selected_text" }%>
```

And then in that partial, I have the javascript from the above link and this code:

```
<div class="simple_editor">
    <input type="button" value="Bold" id="bold">
    <input type="button" value="Italic" id="italic">
    <input type="button" value="Underline" id="underline">

    <div class="input_container">   
iframe stuff goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I haven't gotten far.

Now, when the form loads, I populate the fields via javascript (this part works).
The issue I'm having is not knowing how to do the actual editing with the iframe.

I know I need to set contentEditable, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell if making your own WYSIWYG editor is the goal of your project or just something you need in your project. I would suggest you checkout existing options such as http://ckeditor.com/ for either case. You can learn how they perform different commands and work at making your own editor, or you can just drop it in to your application if you just need an editor and don't feel like spending the time to build one.

Comment: nope, All I need is bold / italic / underline, I don't need all that bulk =\

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. You still can see what their underlying implementation is.